# How do I see that $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, where $V \subset \mathbb R^m$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, let $x_o \in U$, and let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ be differentiable in $x_0 \in U$.

Let $V \subset \mathbb R^m$ be an open neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$.

How do I see that $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ ?

---

I see that $f^{-1}(V)$ is non-empty since $x_0 \in f^{-1}(V)$.

Also, I know that the intersection of two open sets is open !

I know that a mapping $f$ is continuous between metric spaces if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open whenever $V$ is open.

In this case, I don't know whether $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity. Easy to show by definition.

Comment: But we only have that $f$ is differentiable (and hence continuous) **at** $x_0$.

Comment: Sorry V=(-1,2) in my last example with f(x) = x^2 irr(x)